# How to bind BackgroundColor of ListView child to value?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to set the background of a child of a ListView based on the some value.

I tried using a ValueConverter, but it would only update the color when the item is redrawn on the screen. I checked with the debuger, and the Convert method is called, and the right value is returned.

IValue.Convert implementation

```
 return Convert.ToInt32(value) > 0 ? "#E0EBFF" : "#FFFFFF";
```

XAML file:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <converters:QuantityToColorConverter x:Key="QuantityToColorConverter"></converters:QuantityToColorConverter>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ListView > <!-- Options not included for simplicty -->
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View BackgroundColor="#ecf0f1" >
                                    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,10" BackgroundColor="{Binding Path=Quantity,Converter={StaticResource QuantityToColorConverter}}" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
```

The background color should change but it stays the same until the child is scrolled past and then scrolled back to

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
return Convert.ToInt32((value as "Here you put the right type of property").Text)) > 0 ? "" : ""
```

Comment: Case value isn't from a controller, use (value as string)

Comment: You mean in the converter? and the Quantity property is an int

Comment: The converter is working. it returns the expected value, but the grid only changes its color if i scroll past the view and get back at it?

Comment: @BogdanConstantin i think you`ll achieve the right behavior doing the color change by code-behind in C#, probably Binding only read the value on Element Creation or Visual ElementChange, for better results you can go for C# behind or Element.Behaviours on XAML

Comment: It does not work. I tried with data triggers. I tried displaying the quantity, but it is not updating as well. I have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented on both the model and the viewmodel. The list is an ObservableCollection. I can't think of anything else